# Bluetooth and WiFi not working on HP PROBOOK 4430s

Tags: 12.04, wireless, bluetooth, hp

It is showing the bluetooth status "**on**" but when I am trying to setup new device it is not detecting any device.

Even my cell phone is also not detecting it. Please help me with this.

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

fine work with me. there try this :D,

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r) linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms

wget http://media.cdn.ubuntu-de.org/forum/attachments/44/18/3005217-r8168-dkms-8.029.00.tar.gz

sudo tar xvf 3005217-r8168-dkms-8.029.00.tar.gz -C /usr/src

sudo dkms add -m r8168-dkms -v 8.029.00

sudo dkms build -m r8168-dkms -v 8.029.00

sudo dkms install -m r8168-dkms -v 8.029.00 

echo "blacklist r8169" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

sudo modprobe -rfv r8169

sudo modprobe -v r8168
```

Hope will this help you :)